# Not understanding newsletter properly

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am developing one website. For now i just need to design home page for it.

So i made changes from cms/home/content(I am not sure it's good idea or not).

I added newsletter to home page. it's displaying in the top left. 
I want to put it at specific position around the middle of the page.

**So how i can change the position of the newsletter?**

And when i enter any email it gives message "Thanks for your subscription".

**will it make entry to automatically to any table or i have to do it manually ?**

**Can i change this message "Thanks for your subscription".** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for newsletter file call from 
app>design>froentend>YOUR_PACKEGE_NAME>YOUR_THEME_NAME>template>newsletter>subscribe.phtml

you can change design from css

and message come from

/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php

```
 $session->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
```

This can also be edited in /app/locale/en_US/Mage_Newsletter.csv file, and any other language that you wish to support.

```
instead of en_US you can check from your language pack
```

Change "Thank you for your subscription.","Thank you for your subscription."

to

"Thank you for your subscription.","This will be my new message, that I wish to display to users, after subscribing."

and subscriber user details you get from admin

```
Newsletter >Newsletter Subscribers
```

Comment: thanks. But why it isn't showing any other message when user already signed up?

Comment: ok. I found it out myself. I added this  $emailExist = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->load($email, 'subscriber_email');
                if ($emailExist->getId()) {
                        $session->addSuccess($this->__('You are already signed up.'));
                }